# Can't return a view in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I create a code like this in Laravel controller

```
public function __invoke($slug){
    if($slug == 'add_profile'){
        $this->create();
    }
}
```

and then it will calling a method :

```
public function create()
{
    return view('profiles/add');
}
```

but why it can't return a view?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... as vinod said in their answer you are not returning the result of the call to `create` in `__invoke`... but what if  `$slug != 'add_profile'` ? you should still  be returning something from that method either way

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the view in `__invoke()`:

```
return $this->create();
```

Answer (score 1):

In --invoke method you are returning nothing that's why your create method is not called

p

```html
public function __invoke($slug){
    if($slug == 'add_profile'){
        return $this->create();
    }
}
```

paste this code in invoke method